# Values of a limit with parameter

Tags: limits, parametric

Evaluate the values of the limit as the changes of $\lambda \in \mathbb{R}$
$$\lim\limits_{x \to +∞} e^{x-x^3+\lambda\ln(x)}f^{(n)}x$$

with $$f^{(n)}(x)=p_n(x)e^{x^3-x}$$ where $p_n(x)$ is a generic polynomial.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is simply
$$\lim_{x\to\infty}\exp\left(\not x-\not x^3+\lambda\ln(x)+\not x^3-\not x\right)p_n(x)\\
= \lim_{x\to\infty}x^\lambda p_n(x)$$
This limit can be evaluated given $p_n(x),\lambda$.

Comment: Isn't it $\lim_{x\to\infty} x^\lambda p_n(x)$ ?

Comment: @ClementC. Yes - my mistake.

Comment: @ClementC. See my edited answer.

Comment: Ack. Essentially, it only depends on $\lambda$ the leading monomial of $p_n$—that is, its degree and coefficient's sign.

Comment: So let be $ax^n$ the leading monomial, the limit is finite if $\lambda = -n$ and it is $a$. Otherwise if $\lambda > -n$ it goes to +∞ (with $a>0$) or -∞ (with $a<0$)

Comment: @TheMaker94 Exactly.

Comment: Ah and naturally if $\lambda < -n$ the limit is 0.

Comment: @TheMaker94 Yes.